# Delete text between several bookmarks in word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have already checked what I am asking now but I couldn't still solve my problem which is the following:

I try to delete text between two bookmarks in a Word document - that part I have solved. However, I have many bookmark pairs and I would like to delete text in between each pair. So, I decided to enter the bookmarks in two arrays: arr_B for beginning of the text part and arr_E for the end of the text part and between them text should be deleted. I have tried like this:

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim arr_B As Variant
Dim arr_E As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim element As Variant

arr_B = Array("B1_RSD1", "B2_RSD2")
arr_E = Array("E1_RSD1", "E2_RSD2")

    For Each element In arr_B
        For Each element In arr_E
        Set rngStart = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(i).Range
        Set rngEnd = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("k").Range
        ActiveDocument.Range(rngStart.Start, rngEnd.End).Select
        Selection.Delete
        Exit For
        Next k
    Next i

End Sub
```

However, above code gives the error

> For control variable already in use

I couldn't find out how to solve this problem. I would appreciate any help and many thanks in advance.

Comment: For the error you're seeing:

Just don't use `element` for more than one `For` loop. Declare, for example:  `Dim element_B as Variant, element_E as Variant` and then use those in their respective `For` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Given the similarity of your bookmark names, it appears you don't even need an array. Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, Rng As Range, StrTxt As String
With ActiveDocument
  For i = 1 To .Bookmarks.Count / 2
    StrTxt = i & "_RSD" & i
    If .Bookmarks.Exists("B" & StrTxt) And .Bookmarks.Exists("E" & StrTxt) Then
      Set Rng = .Bookmarks("B" & StrTxt).Range
      With Rng
        .End = .Bookmarks("E" & StrTxt).Range.End
        .Delete
      End With
    End If
  Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: That does it. Thank you very much macropod!